# Openedge: disable single cell in browse

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Is it possible to disable a single cell instead of a full column of a browse in progress?

Now I do:

```
assign variable:read-only in browse {&browse-name} = true.
```

(This disables the whole column)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Until the row that contains the cell that you want to disable is realized there is no way to tell the compiler what to disable.  So it is a run-time decision and, therefore, you would have to do it with a ROW-DISPLAY trigger.

That involves getting a buffer handle and then the proper field.  Something like (untested):

```
browseColumnBufferHandle:buffer-field( columnName ):read-only = true
```